# How do I fix the css to have two columns on small screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two sections of my site, the menu down the left and the content on the right. On small screens I need the menu to be at the top, with the content centered in the middle.

After some issues, I was able to place the content next to the menu on large screens, but it's done pushing it to the left- meaning that on the smaller windows it does the same.

I've tried floats, changing pixels to and from %'s, aligning floats to left and to the right, clearing floats, changing widths and heights of them both, and changing display to inline-block and inline. (There are more things, but I can't remember.)
The only thing that almost works is the margin-left:30% for the main content.

**My question:**
***What code do I need to change to have the content beside the menu on larger screens, but underneath on smaller ones-without it being pushed to one side?***

(I removed the content so it just shows the layout in it's base form.)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test_css.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--menu below-->
<div class="menu">  
 <ul class="sidenav">
     <li><h3>menu:</h3></li>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<!--End of the menu.-->

<!--header-->
<div class="header">
 <br />
 <h1>Header</h1>
     <a></a>
 <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>
</div>
<!--end of header section-->

<div class="main">
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <a></a>
 <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>

 <h1>Main content</h1>
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>
</div>

<!--footer content below-->
<div id="footer">
 <h4>Staff:</h4>
 <h5>1</h5>
 <h5>2</h5>
 <h5>3</h5>
 <h6>Last updated: --/--/----</h6>
</div>
<!--end of footer content-->
</body>
```

And the css:

```
/* background and font face for web page-!important! */
body {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#47807E;
    background-image: url('Home_background.png');
    background-position:top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive {

    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}

ul{
    width: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

/* formatting for content areas */
div.header {
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 63%;
    padding:0;
}

div.main {
    margin-left:30%;
    width: 63%;
    padding:0;
}

div.footer {
width: 30%;
float: right;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
}


/* styling for font and images */




/* side navigation testing, need to fix formatting. */
ul.sidenav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background-colour: #ccffff;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0%;
}

ul.sidenav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ccffff;
}

ul.sidenav li a.active {
    background-color: #003333;
    color:white;
}

ul.sidenav li a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color:#003333;
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
ul.sidenav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }   
}

ul.sidenav li a {
    float: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.content {margin-left: 0;}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
ul.sidenav li a{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    }
}
```

***What I'm hoping for:***
Larger window: *Navigation menu on the left, content on the right.*
Smaller window: *Menu on the top, content centered beneath.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already done the responsive task for smaller devices just add below css in `@media screen and (max-width:900px)` media query for minor tweaks.

```
div.header,
div.main {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

> **Also make sure you add `viewport` meta in your page `head` if not just add below code in you page `head`**. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

```css
/* background and font face for web page-!important! */
body {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#47807E;
    background-image: url('Home_background.png');
    background-position:top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive {

    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}

ul{
    width: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

/* formatting for content areas */
div.header {
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 63%;
    padding:0;
}

div.main {
    margin-left:30%;
    width: 63%;
    padding:0;
}

div.footer {
width: 30%;
float: right;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
}


/* styling for font and images */




/* side navigation testing, need to fix formatting. */
ul.sidenav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background-colour: #ccffff;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0%;
}

ul.sidenav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ccffff;
}

ul.sidenav li a.active {
    background-color: #003333;
    color:white;
}

ul.sidenav li a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color:#003333;
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
ul.sidenav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }   
    div.header,
    div.main {
      margin-left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
}

ul.sidenav li a {
    float: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.content {margin-left: 0;}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
ul.sidenav li a{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!--menu below-->
<div class="menu">  
 <ul class="sidenav">
     <li><h3>menu:</h3></li>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<!--End of the menu.-->

<!--header-->
<div class="header">
 <br />
 <h1>Header</h1>
     <a></a>
 <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>
</div>
<!--end of header section-->

<div class="main">
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <a></a>
 <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>

 <h1>Main content</h1>
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <h2>Main content</h2>
 <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>
</div>

<!--footer content below-->
<div id="footer">
 <h4>Staff:</h4>
 <h5>1</h5>
 <h5>2</h5>
 <h5>3</h5>
 <h6>Last updated: --/--/----</h6>
</div>
<!--end of footer content-->
```

Comment: This worked just as I wanted thank you! It's rather annoying I missed that one little thing though. Thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically, what you need to achieve that is to wrap the whole document into a single div wrapper.

Here I added a div element with id of `#main`. And wrapped the main content into a div with classname of `.content`. The structure would look like this.

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="menu">
    <!-- other codes -->
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- other codes -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**and the styling for the root div**

```
#main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh; // take up the whole viewport height
 overflow: hidden; // remove the scrollbar for overflow items
 display: flex;
}
```

**and the styling for the content and menu div**

```
.content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; // add the vertical scroll bar for content
}

.menu {
  display: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

**and this is what it will look like.**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#47807E;
    background-image: url('Home_background.png');
    background-position:top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  display: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.responsive {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}

ul{
    width: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

/* formatting for content areas */
.header {
    padding:0;
}

.main {
    padding:0;
}

.footer {
width: 30%;
float: right;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
}


/* styling for font and images */




/* side navigation testing, need to fix formatting. */
.sidenav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background-colour: #ccffff;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0%;
}

.sidenav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ccffff;
}

.sidenav li a.active {
    background-color: #003333;
    color:white;
}

.sidenav li a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color:#003333;
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  #main {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  
  .sidenav {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
  } 
  .sidenav li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidenav li a{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="menu">  
   <ul class="sidenav">
       <li><h3>menu:</h3></li>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
           <li>4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<!--End of the menu.-->
  <div class="content">
    <!--header-->
    <div class="header">
     <br />
     <h1>Header</h1>
         <a></a>
     <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>
    </div>
    <!--end of header section-->

    <div class="main">
     <h2>Main content</h2>
     <h2>Main content</h2>
     <a></a>
     <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>

     <h1>Main content</h1>
     <h2>Main content</h2>
     <h2>Main content</h2>
     <p class="hr">____________________________________</p>
    </div>

    <!--footer content below-->
    <div id="footer">
     <h4>Staff:</h4>
     <h5>1</h5>
     <h5>2</h5>
     <h5>3</h5>
     <h6>Last updated: --/--/----</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I did try your suggestion but I think I messed the code up a little as I typed it in. Couldn't seem to get it to work annoyingly. :( I managed to get it working with the other answer in the end though.